# Merging 2D Array with Sorted Rows of Uneven Size into Sorted 1D Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, heap, mergesort

I'm trying to figure out how to merge a `2D` int array containing several rows of uneven size into one sorted 1D int array in Java.

For example, if my 2D array is something like `[[2, 8], [16, 35], [1, 4], [5, 7, 19]]` it would merge into a sorted 1D array `[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 16, 19, 35]`.

The header for my function looks like this, with the semi-sorted 2D array and the 1D array being sorted into are arguments:

```
public void mergeTo1D(int[][] sorted, int[] origArray) {

// Code goes here

}
```

I've seen some solutions on here that use a min-heap but I have no idea how to implement or work with that since I'm just getting started learning data structures.

Comment: You can follow `merge sort` approach.

Comment: How big are these arrays? If they're reasonably small, just copy everything into a 1D array and sort it. Otherwise, you can do a [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) in O(n log k), where k is the number of rows, and n is the total number of items.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use k-way merge (which is a generalization of merge sort).

What you have here are n sorted lists, with a max size of k. 
keep a min-heap that contains the smallest element from each list. Also, keep a result list.

Then, each time pop the min of the heap. Let this number be x, and say it was taken from row i. Append x to the result list, and add to the min heap the next number in row i (if such number exists)

Repeat until you finished going through all arrays.

The complexity is O(n*k*logn) - pretty efficient considering you are sorting n*k elements, and need to go over all of them.